# Convert to KO JS Mapping my code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I recently started to work with KnockoutJS and i managed to do a simple app to show my data from CouchDB. What i noticed is if i have more data and more nested data i need to appply the mapping plugin in order to get my data more flexible. Some question and answers here are about this plugin but i didn't know how to apply this plugin on my existing web-app.

I recently came a to a problem, i wanted to get the specdial data from my converter and then show it with a computed variable. Even this code does not apply with my view model or i need to apply the plugin : `self.Converter = ko.observable(Converter);`

So here is my mainJS.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.myfield =  ko.observableArray([]);
    self.investigator = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.preparatorInfos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.enumInfos = ko.observableArray([]);

    //self.Converter = ko.observable(Converter);
    //self.Converter = ko.observable(data.Converter);

    self.selectDivs = ko.observableArray(['Properties', 'Implements']);
    self.selectedDiv = ko.observable();

    self.selectDivs2 = ko.observableArray(['Properties', 'Requires']);
    self.selectedDiv2 = ko.observable();

  }
 var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/helloworld');

  var vm = new ViewModel();


  db.query("bricksetup/docs").then(function(result) {
    var data = result;
    console.log(data);
    vm.myfield(data.rows);
  });
  db.query("InvestigatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) {  
    var data = result;
    console.log(data);
    vm.investigator(data.rows);
  });

  db.query("PreparatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
    var data = result;
    console.log(data);
    vm.preparatorInfos(data.rows);
  });

  db.query("EnumInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
    var data = result;
    console.log(data);
    vm.enumInfos(data.rows);
  });

  ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And my View:

```
 <!-- BRICKINFOS -->
      <div id="tab1" class="col s12">
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" data-bind="foreach:myfield">
            <li  data-bind="with: value">
              <div class="collapsible-header">
                <i class="material-icons">view_stream</i>
                <p class="blue-text" data-bind="text: TypeName"></p>
              </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"> 
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>AssemblyName:</b> <span data-bind="text: AssemblyName"></span></p>
                  <!-- ko if: Description -->
                   <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Description:</b> <span data-bind="text: Description"></span></p>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Name: </b><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></p>
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Obsolete: </b><span data-bind="text: Obsolete"></span></p>
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>TypeName: </b><span data-bind="text: TypeName"></span></p>

                   <div class="row">
                      <form class="col s12">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col s12 m12">
                                <div class="col s12 m4 padding_select">
                                  <select class="browser-default " 
                                  data-bind="options: $root.selectDivs,
                                            value: $root.selectedDiv,
                                            optionsCaption: 'Choose'">
                                  </select>
                                </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                                <div class="col s6 m6" >
                                   <div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Properties'" id="Properties">
                                   <!-- ko if: Properties.Properties == ''-->
                                     <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>is nothing set
                                   <!-- /ko -->
                                   <!-- ko ifnot: Properties.Properties == ''-->
                                    <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: Properties.Properties">
                                      <li class="space_bottom">  
                                      <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></br>        
                                      <b>Converter: </b><span class="converter_class" data-bind="text: converterNames[Converter]"></span></br>      
                                      <b>Validation Type: </b><span class="validation_class" data-bind="text:validationName[ValidationType] "></span></br>
                                      <!-- ko if: EnumTypeName -->
                                      <b>EnumType: </b><span class="validation_class" data-bind="text: EnumTypeName"></span></br>
                                      <!-- /ko -->
                                      <!-- ko if: Description -->
                                      <b>Description: </b><span class="validation_class" data-bind="text: Description"></span></br>
                                      <!-- /ko -->
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                  </div>
                                  <div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Implements'" id="Implements">
                                    <p class="blue-text padding_p">Implements Interfaces</p>
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: Implements.Interfaces">
                                      <li><b>TypeName:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.TypeName"></span><br></li>
                                    </ul> 
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                      </form>
                    </div><!-- end row -->
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

How my data looks:

[image]

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I also tried with this: `self.converter = ko.observable(Converter);
` without success

Comment: It's quite unclear to me what you're asking, not in the least because there is a *lot* of code that's probably not relevant to the question. See [mcve] for help on editing the question.

Comment: i want to apply mapping plugin, to my existing viewmodel

Comment: Could be, but that's in no way related to my comment. I'm talking about all the irrelevant code obscuring the problem to us, e.g. all those classes, extra observables, complicated bootstrap helper elements, couchdb queries, etc. You can't just dump uncleaned code like that and expect volunteers to wade through the whole thing IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're asking how to use KO mapping, it would be:

instead of

```
db.query("PreparatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
    var data = result;
    console.log(data);
    vm.preparatorInfos(data.rows);
});
```

it would become:

```
db.query("PreparatorInfos/docs").then(function(result) { 
    var data = result;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm.preparatorInfos);
});
```